# How can I create an image object from an FileUpload control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a FileUpload control.  I am trying to save the file that is uploaded (an image) and also save several thumbnail copies of the file.

When I try something like this:

System.Drawing.Image imgOriginal = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(PhotoUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);

I get an "System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid."

I also tried using the PhotoUpload.FileBytes to create the image from the file bytes instead of the InputStream, but the same error occurs.

The uploaded file is a jpg.  I know it's a valid jpg since it saves the original ok.

Edit: This code actually does work.  The Parameter is not valid was due to the PhotoUpload.PostedFile.InputStream being empty... which seems to be an entirely different issue.  It looks like after I save the original the fileupload stream goes away.

Edit: Found out that the InputStream of a FileUpload can only be read/consumed one time and then it is gone.

To get around that I saved the fileupload filebytes into a byte array and used the byte array to create copies of the image.

Code:

```
// Copy the FileBytes into a byte array
byte[] imageData = PhotoUpload.FileBytes;

// Create a stream from the byte array if you want to save it somewhere:
System.IO.Stream myStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData);

// Or create an image from the stream as many times as needed:
System.Drawing.Image imgOriginal = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myStream);
```

Comment: Instead of trying to open the file from the stream, why don't you open the physical file that's saved on the disk?

Comment: I don't save the file to the file system.  I save it to another server via a web service.  So I want to pass the web service 2 files: the orginal (this is working ok) and the thumbnail (not working yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this link

[ASP Net - How to pass a postedfile to a system.drawing.image](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t153119-how-to-pass-a-postedfile-to-a-system-drawing-image.html)

> Here's my function call:
>
> uploadAndSizeImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream
>   (uploadedFileMD.PostedFile.InputStream))
>
> I'm getting this error:
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid
>   parameter used.
>
> Google isn't turning up much though I
>   did find a reference to it possibly
>   being caused by the stream reader
>   being at the end of the stream and me
>   needing to reset it to position one.
>   But that was kind of vague and not
>   really sure if it applies here.

Does this help?

EDIT:

Also, have you tried manually reading the file using something like

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"Image.JPG");
byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Or saving a temp copy from the FileUpload and loading the image from file?

Comment: Thanks, this did help, though my issue now is not the conversion.  I found out that my FileUpload content is gone when I make this call... somewhere before I make this call I save the file upload and after that it is gone... not sure if that makes any sense.  But now I need to figure out how to keep the fileupload content.

Comment: why my fileupload.PostedFile is returning "" even when I have selected a file?